# VS2010 Find all references to the project in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there an easy way to find all references to the project in solution in VS2010? 
In fact I have a solution with 43 projects in it and I want to make sure there are no projects that have references to Project#N.

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Easy but dull way: right-click on solution, choose **Project Dependencies**, choose the first project in the **Projects** drop down list, and use down arrow to scroll through projects. For each project in **Project** box look if your project of interested checked in the list - that's most probably will make your list.

Or you can use Resharper for this:

- Right-click on module and choose [Find Code Dependent on Module](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Finding_Code_Dependent_on_Modules.html) to find all projects which really use this module (this will **not** show references which exist, but not used).
- Right-click on module and choose [Project Hierarchy](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Project_Hierarchy.html), then click "Referencing projects" to see all project references

Comment: "Find Code Dependent on Module" from Resharper works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: At least the first part of the answer is wrong. It lists dependencies for the projects, not dependent projects.

Comment: that's why you need to scroll through each and every project

Answer (score 15):

The build-in Project Dependencies command only works the other way, i.e., it finds a given project's dependencies, not projects dependent on the given one—unless of course you feel like selecting each of your 200 projects in turn in the dropdown, and then for each project, scrolling down the also voluminous list below to see if the project of interest is included.

Instead, in the absence of Resharper you can use Find in Files (`CTRL` `SHIFT` `F`) to list projects in the solution that refer to the project of interest:

[image]

Comment: This approach shows promise, but I found that it only works for my NetStandard and .NET Core projects; it doesn't find any references from my classic .NET Framework projects.

Answer (score 8):

If you are lazy and do not have Resharper, you can also unload the project, try building the solution again and see wich projects fail building.

Comment: Unloading the project will not break the build with the new .NET Core csproj files.

Comment: Beware that, although selecting to **Remove** the project will show you the reference errors, it will also remove the references to the now-deleted project in all other projects that referenced it. I made this mistake, and if it weren't for Git undo, I'd have to manually add back references in a dozen projects

Answer (score 0):

A few of these non-Resharper answers are good, but only work for certain project types and not others.

I do not have Resharper and DO have a mix of project types (NetStandard, .NET Core, .NET Framework, UWP) and here is a simple approach that worked for me:

First, *unload* the project of interest (in my example, `TWW.Common.DataModel`).

Go to your *Error List*, select `Entire Solution`, enable the display of Warnings, and in the search field, enter "The referenced component"*. It will filter the list to show all projects that now have this missing reference:

[image: Error list]

* or whatever text Visual Studio uses for this type of warning.